# MySQL SELECT function to sum current data

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a query that return something like this:

```
| ID | Val |  
| 0  | 10  |     
| 1  | 20  |     
| 2  | 30  |
```

But instead of that, I want something like this:

```
| ID | Val | Sum |   
| 0  | 10  |  10 |   
| 1  | 20  |  30 |   
| 2  | 30  |  60 |
```

Is that a way to do it on the query (I'm using MySQL)?

Tks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called cumulative sum.

In `Oracle` and `PostgreSQL`, it is calculated using a window function:

```
SELECT  id, val, SUM() OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM    mytable
```

However, `MySQL` does not support it.

In `MySQL`, you can calculate it using session variables:

```
SET @s = 0;

SELECT  id, val, @s := @s + val
FROM    mytable
ORDER BY
        id
;
```

or in a pure set-based but less efficient way:

```
SELECT  t1.id, t1.val, SUM(t2.val)
FROM    mytable t1
JOIN    mytable t2
ON      t2.id <= t1.id
GROUP BY
        t1.id
;
```

Answer (score 3):

Would something like this work for your purposes?  (Warning, potentially really darned slow with the subselect).

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.val, (SELECT SUM(val) FROM table AS t2 WHERE t2.id <= t1.id) 'sum'
   FROM table AS t1
   ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the table name is t, you can use a query like this:

```
select t.id, t.val, sum(t2.val) Sum
  from t, t t2
 where t2.id <= t.id
group by t.id, t.val
```

(tested in Oracle)