# Select with grouping in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables :

'pay'

```
|id_tax|value|id_currency|
--------------------------
|1     |100  |12         |
|1     |200  |12         |
|1     |300  |13         |
|2     |200  |12         |
|2     |200  |12         |
--------------------------
```

'rate'

```
|id_currency|rate|
------------------
|12         |1   |
|13         |6,12|
------------------
```

What SQL query will result in this?

```
|id_tax|value               |
-----------------------------
|1     |100*1+200*1+300*6,12|
|2     |200*1+200*1         |
-----------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  id_tax, SUM(value * rate)
FROM    pay p
JOIN    rate r
ON      r.id_currency = p.id_currency
GROUP BY
        id_tax
```

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, you can calculate it using session variables:

```
SET @s = 0; 

SELECT  id_tax, @s := s +(value * rate)
FROM    pay p
JOIN    rate r
ON      r.id_currency = p.id_currency
GROUP BY
   p.id_tax
```

or in a pure set-based but less efficient way:

```
SELECT  pay.id_currency, pay.val, SUM(pay.value * rate.rate)
FROM    pay
JOIN    rate
ON      rate.id_currency = pay.id_currency
GROUP BY
        pay.id_tax
```

Comment: He wants plain sums, not cumulative. Also, when copying my answer from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5462205/mysql-select-function-to-sum-current-data/5462250#5462250 , you could, I don't know, at least change wording, or something.