# function MSUM of BI

Tags: sql, oracle

hi guys I have a simple question about how to use the funcion MSUM of Oracle BI in sql developer, I don't even know if this is posible, it is?

Comment: Please be more specific. By MSUM, do you mean a **cumulative sum** function? Example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5462250/3061852

Comment: Can you give us an example of some data and what you want the result to be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your example data, here's how I would do a *moving sum* (or *cumulative sum*). You can find more info in [Oracle Analytic Functions.](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions004.htm#SQLRF06174)

```
create table test (id number, value number);
insert into test values (1, 100);
insert into test values (2, 300);
insert into test values (3, 500);
insert into test values (4, 800);

select id, value,
    sum(value) over (order by id rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as total
from test
order by id;
```

Output:

```
1   100 100
2   300 400
3   500 900
4   800 1700
```